# Get product collection from a category id

Tags: magento-1, collection, product-collection

I am trying to get a collection of products from a category id.  A few things I have tried are in the block :

```
 $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(123)
        ->getProductCollection();
```

and

```
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(123);
    $products = $category->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category)
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'simple')
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

also tried just doing it from the phtml

```
$oCatId = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(769); 
        $products->addCategoryFilter($oCatId);
```

None of this works but I am not seeing any errors either.    I saw another post that seems like the same question : [Magento - Get Products from Specific Category](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3441/magento-get-products-from-specific-category) but that method did not work for me either.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 34):

Try this:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id)
 ->getProductCollection()
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // add all attributes - optional
 ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1) // enabled
 ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4) //visibility in catalog,search
 ->setOrder('price', 'ASC'); //sets the order by price
```

<sub>Source: http://overlycaffeinated.com/blog/2011/02/get-all-sale-products-from-a-category-in-magento/</sub>

This should work because it adds the category filter for you by virtue of already having the category loaded:

**Mage_Catalog_Model_Category**

```
public function getProductCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($this);
    return $collection;
}
```

**Wait, it still doesn't work!**

Ok, so you may have larger issues, presumably something overwriting `getProductCollection`. So let's try circumventing that convenience method:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
        ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I feel closer but still floundering.  Using your last method, I added  `foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getId();
 }` and I do get a series of ids.  However when I try `echo $product->getName();` nothing.  I tried adding `->addAttributeToSelect('*')` also but nope.  Thanks for any more help.

Comment: @philwinkle Is there a way to get all products for a category? I'm having trouble getting ones that are disabled. I'm using `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->addCategoryFilter($category)->addAttributeToSelect('sku');`

Answer (score 10):

How to load a product collection with all data that you usually need for product lists in the frontend:

```
$_categoryId = 123;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categoryId );
$productCollection = $category->getProductCollection();
$productCollection
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite();
```

This prepares the product collection to load the necessary data to display prices, the product link and any attributes configured as "used in product listing", but not more.

Comment: How can I limit the results? `->limit(5)` didn't work.

Comment: `->setPageSize(5)`

Comment: @fschmengler you miss `;` after `$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(123)` code

Answer (score 6):

This below code will give you product collection from category id 10.

```
$categoryId = 10;    
$products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

Comment: why to use singleton?

Answer (score 3):

**The code to get product collection from specific category id:**

```
$categoryId = 12;
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                       ->addCategoryFilter($categoryId);
```

Comment: perfect!!! +1  :)

Comment: where $category=$categoryId?

Answer (score 2):

Below piece of code is much simpler and efficient than loading product collection and filtering using it's attributes,

```
$categoryId = 32; // Replace with your category

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                 ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                 ->load($categoryId);

Mage::register('current_category', $category);

$products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer')->getProductCollection();

echo $products->getSize();
```

Answer (score -1):

In Magento 2 try this forget category collection using category ID

```
  $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
  $subCategory =  $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')-> 
         load('categorey_id');
  foreach($subCategory as $subcat)
   { 
        print_r($subcat->getData();
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

$categoryid = 123; // Category Id

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->load($categoryid);
$collection = $category->getProductCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); 

foreach ($_productCollection as $_product) { ?>
    <div class="pr_section">
        <div class="pr_desc">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true); // Reviews ?>
                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                <?php echo $_product->getShortDescription();?>

                <?php if(!$_product->canConfigure() && $_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <p><button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button></p>
                <?php elseif($_product->getStockItem() && $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()): ?>
                    <p><a title="<?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?>" class="button btn-cart" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('View Details') ?></a></p>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <div class="pr_img">
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> 
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Get product collection with detail. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I think necroposting wasn't necessary as there are enough answers to this question. Furthermore, your use of `new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category()` is questionnable.