# Faster way to load media images in a product collection

Tags: product, product-collection, product-images, media

**TL;DR**: How do I load the product images/gallery without loading the whole product?

I want to load the images on a product. What I do in the *.phtml*

```
$_popularCollection = $this->getPopularCollection();
foreach ($_popularCollection as $_product):
    // the rest
    $mediaGallery = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
endforeach;
//the rest
```

What I do in the Block class:

```
public function getPopularCollection() {
    // http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/5838/3089

    // no category
    if ( is_null( $this->getCategoryId() ) )
        return false;

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Category $category */
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load( (int)$this->getCategoryId() );

    /** @var Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $_popularCollection */
    $_popularCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResourceCollection();
    $_popularCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $_popularCollection->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $_popularCollection->addCategoryFilter($category);

    return $_popularCollection;
}
```

This works But I load everything: `$_popularCollection->addAttributeToSelect(*);`

I tried `$_popularCollection->addAttributeToSelect('media_gallery');`
But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`addAttributeToSelect('media_gallery')` is not working as media_gallery will come from complicated logic.

You can get easy `media_gallery` data *inside at loop* by loading the *full product model* But it will take a lot of memory in this case.

### Use Backend model of `media_gallery` attribute & `afterload` of product Model

For getting `media_gallery` attribute value *without full product load* **(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ProductID))** .

You can use  `afterLoad()`, using this function call `backend model` of
`media_gallery`  `eav attribute` load the media image. This is much faster than full model `load(Mage::getModel('ctalog/product')->load($ProductID))`

```
foreach($his->getPopularCollection() as $product){
    $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
    $media_gallery = $attributes['media_gallery'];
    $backend = $media_gallery->getBackend();
    $backend->afterLoad($product); 
    $mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        /* get Image one by  using loop*/
        foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
        echo ($image->getUrl());
        }     

echo "<br/>..........................................<br/>";


}
```

Comment: Yes that worked

Comment: nice! it worked

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer works, but involves loading all the product attributes into memory when perhaps they are unnecessary.

To take a slightly more surgical approach (tested in 1.9.2.2 CE) do

```
$attributeCode = 'media_gallery';
$attribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode);
$backend = $attribute->getBackend();
$backend->afterLoad($product);
```

This way you only load the media_gallery attribute itself.

Comment: It's much better solution than accepted answer

Answer (score 5):

I know the question is old and that it already has a correct answer, but it is not bad to recommend another method that can be useful to the community:
Before `$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()`

You can try:

```
$_product->load('media_gallery');//load media gallery attributes
$mediaGallery = $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

Taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890616/get-product-media-gallery-images-from-a-product-collection-in-magento#23804663

Comment: Nice find! However, I must point out that the solution described by +amit-bera above is significantly faster and less memory and database intensive. [Edit: The approach by +aaron-bonner is actually even faster.]

Comment: No. This a bad answer. You can't load specific data on a product this way, it just calls beforeLoad() and afterLoad() on the product, and does not change the already existing data on the model because the database call won't return anything from this function. Look at the load() function definition on Mage_Core_Model_Abstract and Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract. What you're doing here is just almost a full load of the product.