# Get product baseimage without product object

Tags: image, product-images

How can i get the product `base-image` without loading the whole `product object` ? I have `product-id,sku`.[I know we can get product `base image` from `product object`]

Is there any best method or trick available for that ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
$model = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product');
$img = $model->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'image', $storeId);
```

For "Small image" use `small_image` and for "Thumbnail" `thumbnail`.
Similar question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924226/magento-product-attribute-get-value).

Comment: good try... ) ..

Answer (score 1):

In this case you use  `afterload()` function.

- First load product by `loadByAttribute()` ,which does not load  full image.It take data from product collection
- then using `afterLoad()`  and using image `backend models of base image attribute` you can get
  image easily

  ```
  $sku='wbk003c';

  $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$sku);

  $attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
      $image = $attributes['image'];
      $backend = $image->getBackend();
      $backend->afterLoad($product); 
     echo  $Theimage = $product->getImage();
  ```

Anther example is :

[Faster way to load media images in a product collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65218/faster-way-to-load-media-images-in-a-product-collection/65234#65234)

Comment: Thanks amit for answer but i don't want to load product,,,is there any trick or sql query to check product base image?

Comment: i will see ..... and you have put down vote...

Comment: no amit i didn't do that,,,and i will never put down your vote ,,because i know the your valuable contribution,,,But still +1 from me