# Get specific images for Facebook Product Catalog

Tags: magento-1.9, xmlrpc, google-product-feeds

I try to setup a XML feed so can add my products to Facebook Product Catalog. After search I found this but it get all product images.

```
    function getProductData($iProduct) {
      Mage::getmodel( 'catalog/product' );
        $aData['title'] = mb_substr( $oProduct->getName(  ), 0, 299, 'UTF-8' );
        $aData['description'] = strip_tags( $oProduct->getShortDescription(  ) );
        $oProduct->getFinalPrice(  );
        $_finalPrice = ;
        $aData['price'] = preg_replace( '/,/', '.', Mage::helper( 'tax' )->getPrice( $oProduct, $_finalPrice, true ) );
        $aData['link'] = mb_substr( $oProduct->getProductUrl(  ), 0, 299, 'UTF-8' );
        $aData['image_link_large'] = mb_substr( Mage::getbaseurl( URL_TYPE_MEDIA ) . 'catalog/product' . $oProduct->getImage(  ), 0, 399, 'UTF-8' );
```

What I want is to get only the images that the filename contain "facebook".
Something like this "image01facebook.jpg" or "image01_facebook.jpg"

Comment: After a little search I realize that getImage refer to Base Image of product. Then I found this: `$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();` and I wonder if `$aData['image_link_large'] =$_product->getMediaGalleryImages()->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'LABEL_NAME')->getUrl();` do the job simply adding facebook to label name

Answer (score 2):

As you want to tried with media label then  it can be good idea.

But for getting media image then you need to load full product object by product id`( i.e Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($ProductId))` and that is not good idea because it  ***take lot of time to execute  and  lot of memory to***.If you want to this then use any  faster way to media image  like
[Faster way to load media images in a product collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/65234/4564).

If you have **max 1 image for facebook receptively each produc**t then i will  suggest to ***you create a new image attribute from  manage attribute*** and enable this attribute setting **used in product listing  =yes.**

Comment: My site image format is 1:1. The optimum size for images for Facebook Product Catalog is 1200x630px. I want to upload each image to product so I can export the XML file with this image. Can you tell me please how to modify `$aData['image_link_large']`

Comment: I try your suggestion. I have added a image attribute. How can I get this image to XML?