# On product hover all the images from the gallery 1 by 1

Tags: magento-1.9, jquery, slideshow

I understand how to display an image based on my selection from backend for hover on the product but i am trying to display 1 by 1 sequencely with a delay
For a starting point i have this code that might help, it will load all the images for this product on the gallery, use this on an item somewhere (list.phtml)

```
<?php 
    $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();
 ?>
<?php 
   if($_images){?>          
  <?php  $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++;?>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="<?=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>"alt="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" width="222px" height="222px" />
   </a>             
<?php  } ?>
<?php  } ?>
```

I am thinking with the help of jQuery to do this but i do not want all the images to load on a category cause this will have waiting time, it should load 1 by 1 once the "slideshow' inside the main image will start.

anyone have some free time to play with this and help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is something like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104115/hover-starts-a-simple-slideshow

Your request isn't very Magento related, but please don't load the `product` model in a loop, you're shooting yourself in the foot here.

Comment: Thank you Mayers this is a good starting point (exact what i was looking to study) about loading the product in the loop is also my concern as i do not want to kill the database. Any ideas how to make it better?It should be loaded inside list.phtml so we speak about 36 products X all their images for every page.

Comment: @spanakorizo Have a look there: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65218/faster-way-to-load-media-images-in-a-product-collection That's a better way to do it. But in this situation, I would still display less than 36 (seems a lot for Magento). Maybe display 12, and use infinite scroll, that would be a reliable solution