# how to get all images of a particular product

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, soap-api-v2, android

How to **get all images of a particular product** by using this code i am able to **fetch only single image of the particular product.**.

Please help i am new to this.

```
<?php 
// Get products in category
require_once('../app/Mage.php');//Path to Magento umask(0);

if(isset($_GET["categoryId"])){
  $categoryId=$_GET["categoryId"];
    $proxy = new SoapClient('http://www.prashant.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
    $sessionId = $proxy->login('prash', 'prashant123@'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

    $products= $proxy->catalogCategoryAssignedProducts($sessionId,$categoryId);


    $itemDetails=array();
    Mage::app(); 

  foreach ($products as $item) { 

    $product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->product_id);
    $productMediaConfig = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config');
    $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
    $price2=0;
    $price2=$product2->getFinalPrice();
    if($price2==0){
    $price2=$product2->getPrice();
    }



    $desc=$product2->getDescription();
           if($desc==""){
            $desc="blank";
           }
           $baseImageUrl = $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($product2->getImage());
           if($baseImageUrl=="http://www.prashant.com/media/catalog/product/"){
            $baseImageUrl="http://www.prashant.com/customApi/icon.png";
           }

           //"desc"=>$desc,

           $statusp=$product2->getStatus();
    $statusen= Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED;


    if($statusp==$statusen){
         $itemDetails[]=array(
      "productId"=>$item->product_id,
      "name"=>$product2->getName(),
      "price"=>$product2->getPrice(),
      "spprice"=>$price2,
      "desc"=>$desc,
      "imageurl"=>$baseImageUrl,
      );
    }


  }
  //return array of products
  //echo "<pre>";
  //print_r($itemDetails);
  //echo "</pre>";
  echo json_encode($itemDetails);
  exit();
}else{
  echo "error";
  exit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the following code to avail all the images of a particular product.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(2);
$base = $product->getImage();
$thumb = $product->getThumbnail();
$small = $product->getSmallImage();

foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) 
{ //will load all gallery images in loop
    //print_r($image);
      $file_name = $image->getFile();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Below Variable returns you array of all media images with respect to that product id.

```
 $images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->product_id)->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get products all images by following script including images that are excluded:

`$product->getMediaGalleryImages('images')`

```
$product should be an instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) :?>

<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(100, 100); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName()?>" />

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = $client->catalogProductAttributeMediaList($session, $_productId);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**getImage()** function only able to give you **base image** of a product.

If want to get ***all images of product then you should to call media gallery***.

If you full *product object then you can media images using*
 below code:

```
$mediaGallery = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    /* get Image one by  using loop*/
    foreach ($product2->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
        echo ($image->getUrl());
    $productMediaConfig->getMediaUrl($image->getUrl());
    }
```

after  `$desc=$product2->getDescription();`.

**Note that:** As you have `full load the product model by product2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->product_id);`

Then you media image using `getMediaGalleryImages()`  easily.

If you have collection then use  [Faster way to load media images in a product collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65218/faster-way-to-load-media-images-in-a-product-collection) for getting media image

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(3);//product id 3

    foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
                         echo $image->getUrl();
    }
```