# How to get all products of specific category in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Everyone I am new to **Magento** and **php** and stucked in a problem I am trying to getting all products belongs to specific category (**`category_id=9`**).

This question is also asked so many times on this platform but, anyone of them is not working for me.

**What have I done ?**
 I tried mostly answers available on **https://magento.stackexchange.com**

and all solution of question **[Get product collection from a category id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/get-product-collection-from-a-category-id/78308#78308)**

Below is my code I have tried so far

```
class Wri_HelloWorld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{

/**
 * Index action
 *
 * @access public

 * @return void
 */
public function indexAction() {

    /*echo "Hello";*/

    echo $this->getProducts();

}

private function getProducts(){
    $category_id =9;
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
    echo $category;
    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                    ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                    ->addCategoryFilter($category);

    return $products;
}
```

But this does not print anything.

Below is my **Task TODO Admin Panel**

[image]

Comment: i think function define public function getProducts(){ //code }

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala I am not getting what you are saying

Comment: **1)** Did you closed Curly Brace of Class. ?  **2)** Try to Print `print_r($category); ` **3)** Check the path of your Module `Wri/HelloWorld/IndexController `.  **4)** And also check whether the module is loaded or not in `Admin Dashboard -> System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced -> ` check for your module here.

Comment: **1)** Ya I have closed curly braces of my class **2)**  its print some thing in raw large data **3)** Path is correct **4)** Module is loaded because i have print hello which display when i run this code as see I have comment that code

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala is saying to try making the getProducts function public.  Try `public function getProducts()` instead of `private function getProducts()`.  If that doesn't help, I would try moving the code from the getProducts function directly into the indexAction function.  **It appears that getProducts() is not returning a value to indexAction()**